# Stripe payment_intent succeeded event does not contains invoice id

Tags: javascript, api, stripe-payments

I'm creating product

```
 const product = await stripe.products.create({
                name: 'Charge for messages',
            });
```

then price

```
 const price = await stripe.prices.create({
                unit_amount: parseInt(item.amount),
                currency: 'usd',
                product: product.id,
            });
```

then i have checkout session

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: 'payment',
        customer: item.stripe_customer_id,
        line_items: [
            {
                price: price.id,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        payment_intent_data: {
            description: 'Extra messages'
        },
        success_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/dashboard/invoices?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}`,
    });
```

when user finishes payment i get payment_intend.succed event on webhook but invoice is null. how to have invoice id in invoice?

Comment: Is it for recurring payments ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah no, it's just for one time payment. when i have recurring payment subscription i get invoice id.

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392090/invoice-for-a-one-time-payment-on-stripe)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `invoice_creation` parameter while creating checkout session to create invoice

You can find the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/post-payment-invoices#enable-invoice-creation)

```
   const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: 'payment',
        invoice_creation: {enabled: true},
        customer: item.stripe_customer_id,
        line_items: [
            {
                price: price.id,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        payment_intent_data: {
            description: 'Extra messages'
        },
        success_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/dashboard/invoices?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}`,
    });
```

Comment: i tried this too but payment_intent.succeeded event still does not contain invoice_id.

Comment: okey i solved it. i have charge_id so i retreive charge which contains invoice_id.